# The PIVOT SQL construct or statement is not supported

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

## My Query

```
 SELECT  Sno,TopEmpName,TopEmpID,HighLevel,CH,ED,DIR,GM,AGM,BDM,SMM,LowEmpID,Projectid
 from
 (
 SELECT  projectAllocation.proAllocationID AS Sno, temp.Intro_Name AS TopEmpName,
 projectAllocation. IntrotopLevelEmpID AS TopEmpID, temper.CSShortName AS HighLevel,
 companyStructure.CSShortName AS LowLevel, IntroducerMaster.Intro_Name AS LowEmpName,
 projectAllocation.introLevelEmpID AS LowEmpID, projectAllocation.ProjectID as Projectid
 FROM projectAllocation 
 INNER JOIN IntroducerMaster ON IntroducerMaster.Empid = projectAllocation.introLevelEmpID 
 INNER JOIN IntroducerMaster temp ON temp.Empid = projectAllocation.IntrotopLevelEmpID 
 INNER JOIN companyStructure ON projectAllocation.IntroLeveID = companyStructure.HLevel 
 INNER JOIN companyStructure temper ON projectAllocation.introtopLevelID = temper.HLevel
 WHERE (projectAllocation.ProjectID != 3) 
 )a
 PIVOT
 (
  max(LowEmpName) for LowLevel in(CH,ED,DIR,GM,AGM,BDM,SMM)
 )pvt 
 ORDER BY SMM,BDM,AGM,GM,DIR,ED,CH
```

I'm having a problem on Table Adapter configuration wizard:
"The PIVOT SQL construct or statement is not supported."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all likelihood this is because the designer doesn't support PIVOT, even if sql server does (assuming you are not using an ancient version of sql server). In this case the query will probably (but not necessarily) still be executed. There are not many resources on this online, but have a look [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/4b7fe6f4-abf9-46ce-be5c-d655f1f87fbb/the-over-sql-construct-or-statement-is-not-supported?forum=sqlreportingservices), [here](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?428733-Create-Table-Visual-Studio-SQL-Compact-Vista) and [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30387/SQL-Pivot-and-Table-Adapter).

It is probably easiest to convert your query to a stored procedure (or perhaps a view) and call that.